# How to disable internet explorer lookahead downloader?

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, regex-lookarounds

We have a project with a login page. On login the session is set and the client gets redirected to the webapp.

Everything is working fine except, while we are in production, some internet explorer 8 clients are using a lookahead downloader. Since the singlesignon session is not set yet, the preloader is trying to fetch some javascript files but is presented a loginpage with a javascript extension. Causing the internet explorer browser prompting the user with a security warning and the question to download the javascript file.

We have tried to set a charset in the http-equiv metadata since this was said to stop the lookahead downloader. But with no use, we still get a downloadbox on some clients.

It seems IE is setup to even follow javascript redirects and it looks like there is no possibility to stop this from happening.

Is there anybody who recognizes this and knows a solution, because this is driving me insane.

Comment: Do you have to protect your JavaScript files? Is your security in any way based on secrecy of JS?

Comment: Thanks for your response Tomasz, we don't need to secure that javascript file. But since it is an eclipse RAP project it renders the javascript on the fly with a special hash at the end. But it's a nasty solution to just openup a few files. There has to be a way to just disable this preloading crap, isn't it?

Comment: can't you serve a completely stripped html page without any js/css (or inline it) and only the login form and inputcontrols for IE8 clients? I guess the lookahead crap has nothing in to do in that case because there is nothing to look ahead. After authentication you redirect to your normal page. This will cost me some reputation but maybe the useragent reveals that a lookahead thingy is fetching? A rewrite rule in apache shoud be doable I guess.

Comment: the tomcat login page is a stripped page without any protected css or js. The problem is that the lookahead beast is running in front of the parser so the singlesignon session isn't set when the lookahead thing is trying to fetch the javascript. Maybe the useragent is something I could try but it still is a bit nasty imho.

Comment: edit: it fetches the javascript from the webapp, in a subdir, so the webapp html is loader, js is loader & session isn't set.